# What's wrong with this vb.net code? Open .txt files

Tags: vb.net

What's wrong with this code? I want to open a txt file using OpenFileDialog.

```
 Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Dim strTxtFileName As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    If System.IO.File.Exists(strTxtFileName) Then
        Dim read As New System.IO.StreamReader(strTxtFileName)
        TextBox4.Text = read.ReadToEnd
        read.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

What is happening now is that it just keep opening up a new explorer window when I double click a file or press open. When I exit those windows it just chrashes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't put that code in the FileOk event.

Comment: You have an infinite loop. Presumably you show the OpenFileDialog somewhere first. The user clicks the OK button, where you call ShowDialog() again, where the OK button is clicked, where you call ShowDialog() again, where the OK button is clicked, where you call....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put that code in a diff place. I prefer Using blocks.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
 OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
 Dim strTxtFileName As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
 If System.IO.File.Exists(strTxtFileName) Then
    Using read As New System.IO.StreamReader(strTxtFileName)
     TextBox4.Text = read.ReadToEnd
    End Using ' calls read.Close() for you
 End If
End Sub
```